# Sinch Video/Voice Background Issue

Tags: android, sdk, call, sinch

I am working with an android application, where I am implementing sinch sdk to enable voice/video feature to my app. Is there any way to send custom data with call. Below is my code for sending header with call. But I am receiving empty header on incoming call.

HashMap map = new HashMap(); map.put("appintment_key", "vikas");
Call call = getSinchServiceInterface().callUserVideo(userName,map);

Comment: Can you share your code please

Answer (score 1):

To receive calls when the app is killed you need to enable push with GCM, check out the managedpush section in the docs https://www.sinch.com/docs/voice/android/#pushnotifications

To send custom data, do a callUser with headers allUser(String toUserId,
            Map headers)

Comment: I am putting header when i place a call                                                        Call call = getSinchServiceInterface().callUserVideo(userName);
        call.getHeaders().put(userName,new HashMap<String,String>().put("appintment_key","vikas")); and getting this header when call receive  Log.d(TAG, call.getHeaders().toString()); but i am getting empty headers.

Comment: you need to use callUser(String toUserId, Map<String,String> headers) to set headers

Comment: still i am receiving empty headers on incoming call

Comment: @cjensen I have the same issue as user3351125. When using managed push, the headers somehow get lost. When I am listening on the active connection, I receive the headers in the call. When I'm not listening, so when I only use push, I get the call but without headers.